# "sudo p4 sync -f" results in "User root doesn't exist"

Tags: bash, vagrant, perforce

I'm trying to do `p4 sync -f` on an ubuntu Vagrant box, but that just gives me a stream of "open for write: [filename]: Permission denied". If I do `sudo p4 sync -f`, I immediately get the error "User root doesn't exist." How should I go about debugging this? This problem does not exist when I use `sudo` with other commands.

Comment: what does   su -c "your commands..."  give you?   you need root password, rather than user password, as you'd use with sudo, when prompted.  try first:   su -c whoami

Comment: That command prompts me for a password, unlike sudo. It seems to be part of vagrant's configuration that sudo does not require a password and root is given a random password.

Comment: sure, sudo doesn't prompt you for a password, but says "User root doesn't exist".   There are ways to disable password for specific users, and execute without prompt. You may want to look at /etc/pam.d/su. Why sudo complains, I can't tell you. Probably  "configuration issue" - I suggested su to see whether the same problem shows. As it doesn't, the problem seems to be with sudo

Comment: for sudo you want to look at `visudo` to modify the sudoers file. Do not edit directly. It will define what users/groups are allowed to use sudo. The file `/etc/pam.d/su` controls what is required to `su` to another user. (root by default). If during install you did not setup a traditional root account, but went with an `admin` users, that may change the configuration you need to get sudo working. Not creating a traditional root account is about the only thing I can think of that would give `root doesn't exist`. Some of the other distros give the `admin` install options as well.

Comment: To confirm, this error message does not come from Perforce. (My original thought was that Perforce was assuming a P4USER of 'root', but if it were, you would see the message `Access for user 'foobar' has not been enabled by 'p4 protect'.`)

Comment: The error message doesn't come from Perforce, but it doesn't happen when I use "sudo" with other commands - that's where my confusion is.

Answer (score 2):

Do:

sudo p4 -u YOURUSERNAME sync -f

so that the Perforce command is executing under your Perforce user name rather than "root".

Alternatively:

- set P4USER in your environment explicitly
- chown/chmod the files so you can write to them without sudo
- create (and give permission to) a Perforce user named "root"